# Getting error regarding grouping function not allowed

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
 SELECT Cust 
 FROM Orders
 WHERE  Amount < 250 AND  COUNT(Cust)>1);
```

How can I remove the error such that it satisfies to show customers from order that have order two times or more of amount 250 dollar?

Comment: Please note that whenever you have an error you'd like to tell us about, you should cut & paste the entire message, exactly as it appears, rather than paraphrasing it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing it should be this?

```
SELECT Cust 
FROM Orders
WHERE  Amount < 250
GROUP BY Cust
HAVING Count(*)>1
```

Comment: try with adding semicolon at the end  [   SELECT Cust 
FROM Orders
WHERE  Amount < 250
GROUP BY Cust
HAVING Count(*)>1 ;  ]

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Cust 
FROM Orders
WHERE  Amount < 250
```

So far this is right, the problem is you cannot use an aggregate function E.G `Count` or `Sum` in the `WHERE` clause like that.

You'd need to `Group` it by the `Cust` and then use `HAVING Count(*)>1`.

Like so:

```
SELECT Cust 
FROM Orders
WHERE  Amount < 250
GROUP BY Cust
HAVING Count(*)>1
```